# Ansible Tower API call using OAuth2 Token from Nodejs App

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, ansible, ansible-tower

Can we call Ansible Tower Api by passing only Oauth2 token no username or password?

(Say I want to fetch my inventories from ansible tower by passing only Oauth2 token to my nodejs script. Is that possible?)

If yes, please share syntax of that script.

Script which i have used is giving me correct output but it is using credentials as username and password but i want to do the same task by passing only OAuth2 token(generating from my username and password)

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
var Request = unirest.get('http://<tower-host>/api/v2/inventories');

Request
   .auth({
    user: 'foo',
    pass: 'bar',
})
   .then(function (response) {
    var data = response.body;
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Comment: Hi....WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example! what have you tried from your side ?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/tower-manage.html#ag-token-utility You can use this to create a token pass it as header as suggested by reneg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the authorization token in a header.
Here's an example function:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
function job_inventory(tower_url, token) {
    return fetch(tower_url+ "/api/v2/inventories", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "authorization": "Bearer " + token
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, with multiple permutations of headers, methods, and even though I get a clean token value, it gives this error:

    {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided. To establish a login session, visit /api/login/."}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're providing a token? try console.log in the function to make sure

Comment: hey thanks.  yes, I'm providing a token.  I echo out the value before I use it, and I can confirm I get a token and a session object back.  The problem happens when I go back in to use it.  Thanks for the help.  :)